# Converting Wpf elements to bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

The aim is to convert wpf component to bitmap. If the wpf component is already exist, there is no problem. 
What happend:
1. if this was created programmatically Bitmap is missing. 
2. if i put it in stackpanel, visualization in wpf is successful

The code for creating bitmap

```
private void Create Bitmap
{
 var obj = new Button
            {
                Content = "BLA",
                Background = Brushes.Yellow,
                Foreground = Brushes.Black,
                Width = 150,
                Height = 40
                //RenderSize = new Size(150, 40)
            };
// Failure No bitmap created
    BitmapSource bitmap = StaticPdf.CreateBitmapSourceFromVisual(150, 40, obj, false);
    // Success, wpf show it!
    _commentsTimeLine.Children.Add(obj);

}
```

The Code for the BitmapSourceConverter

```
public static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSourceFromVisual(Double width, Double height, Visual visualToRender,
            Boolean undoTransformation)
        {
            if (visualToRender == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((Int32) Math.Ceiling(width),
                (Int32) Math.Ceiling(height), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            if (undoTransformation)
            {
                DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
                using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
                {
                    VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(visualToRender);
                    dc.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(width, height)));
                }
                bmp.Render(dv);
            }
            else
            {
                bmp.Render(visualToRender);
            }
            return bmp;
        }
```

Im very thankful for every hint

Thanks alot in advance

Best Regards

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28628256/1136211).

Comment: Thanks, its works now. I also find that every object needs to be put in a grid.